# delete facebook apprequests via api with c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I can read all of them like:

```
m_api.GetAsync("/me/apprequests");
```

I can read spesific one like:

```
m_fb.GetAsync("/req number");
```

But i wasnt able to delete them...how can i delete them via the api call? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
m_fb.Delete(requestId.ToString());
```